# Python Lists appending in a function works unexpectedly

Tags: python, list, reference, append, late-binding

I came across this below Python code which is showing an unexpected behavior.

```
def extendList(val, list=[] ):
    list.append(val)
    return list

list1 = extendList(10)
print "value of list1 before = %s" % list1

list2 = extendList(123,[])
list3 = extendList('a')

print "value of list1 after = %s" % list1
```

According to me, the expected output of this code should be:

```
value of list1 before = [10]
value of list1 after = [10]
```

The actual output of this code is:

```
value of list1 before = [10]
value of list1 after = [10, 'a']
```

I am not sure why `list1` would change its value later when list3 is being assigned and append `'a'` to its current value i.e. `[10]`.